# Does PowerPoint presentation require in-text referencing if there is a written script?

Tags: citations, presentation

I have to make a PowerPoint presentation for one of my subjects and it requires a written script. I will be referencing on my written script including in-text referencing. However, I’m unsure when it comes to the PowerPoint if it requires the same in-text referencing or a reference list at the very end. The thing is there will be several references and the assignment requires specifically that only 8 slides are allowed each with the intended question I’m required to talk about in each slide. I’m confused because how am I meant to include all my references and at the same fit everything into that one slide. My referencing style will be Apa 7th edition

Comment: This is a question for whoever set you this assignment

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends significantly on what your professor wants. The straightforward answer is to simply ask your professor. However, erring on the side of caution should not hurt.

You could simply add in-text citations on each slide. If you have text on your slides making claims, you can add citations right there. Then, you can have your final slide be a works cited page.

Another way to cite is to say "according to *source*, *claim*". By specifically mentioning sources when you speak, you can cite them verbally and fix this issue. This would be easier, as the audience is more likely to pick up on your sources, and you can cite claims even if they are not written on your slides.

Even if you did not *need* to cite sources, there would presumably be no harm in doing so.